# When is precomputing a value using TMP ever actually useful?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Scott Meyers in "Effective C++" points at the ability to do e.g. matrix operations in the compiler as a reason for implementing some of your algorithms in template classes/functions.  But these functions can't operate on arguments that are determined at run-time, obviously--they only work for numbers that are written into the program or at best given as arguments to the compiler.  Once the program is compiled, it will be using the same output value, every time it is run.  In that case why not just calculate that value with a regular (non-templated) program, and just write it in to the original program where necessary?  It's not *faster* to calculate e.g. a 1000-pt. fft in the compiler than it is with a regular program surely.

The best I can come up with is if you need to compile different versions of your program for different clients, then TMP might save you some time.  But does this need every actually arise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main advantage of TMP when it comes to matrix operations is not the ability to precompute the result of a matrix operation, but rather the ability to optimize the generated code for doing the actual matrix computation at runtime.  You are correct - it would be pretty unlikely that you'd ever want to precompute a matrix in the program - but it's salmon to want to optimize matrix math at compile-time before the program begins running.  For example, consider this code:

```
 Matrix a, b, c;
 /* ... Initialize these matrices ... */
 Matrix d = a + b + c;
```

This last line uses some overloaded operators to compute a matrix expression.  Using traditional C++ programming techniques, this would work as follows:

1. Compute b * c, returning a temporary matrix object holding the copy.
2. Compute a + b + c, again returning a temporary copy.
3. Copy the result into d.

This is slow - there's no good reason to make any copies of any values here. instead we should just for loop over all indices in the matrices and sum up all the values we find.  However, using a TMP technique called [expression templates](http://www.drdobbs.com/184401627), it's possible to implement these operators in a way that actually does this computation in the intelligent, optimized way rather than the slow, standard way.  It's this family of techniques that I think Meyers was referring to in the book.

The most well-known examples of TMP are simple programs to precompute values at compile time, but in practice it's much more complex techniques like these that actually get used in practice.

Comment: Don't move semantics sort of remove the need for some of these things? Or do I have the wrong impression here?

Comment: Somewhat, but not entirely.  There are some cases where the compiler can use expression templates to detect common subexpressions and only evaluate them once in complex operations, for example.  Move semantics don't give the compiler enough information to do this optimization.